# iChat call forces in-call status bar in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ichat, facetime

Is there a way I can disassociate the iOS Simulator from my iChat calls, currently I am working on my app and I am using iChat for a video call and the in-call status bar comes and I can't toggle it off.

It actually says that it's a FaceTime call.

More:

I am developing an iPhone application and I am using he iOS Simulator application to test it. However I am also using iChat to speak to someone on a video call at the same time on my mac.

Consequently in my iOS simulator, the green in-call status bar is appearing. This is stopping me working on some things in my app and I am trying to find a way to switch it off.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are actually asking.  Can I ask you to edit your question to include further detail of what you are trying to do?  Thanks, Dan

Comment: Great, thanks - I can't answer it, but the question is much more easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the iPhone simulator, but if this was happening on an actual iPhone, I would associate the phone with a different Apple ID.

Can you do that in the simulator?